# Endash for minus sign instead of hyphen for matlab

Tags: matlab

So here's my code:

```
set(groot, 'defaultAxesTickLabelInterpreter', 'latex') %For axes; 
ax = gca;
yticklabels(ax, strrep(yticklabels(ax),'--','–'));
set(ax,'ticklabelinterpreter','tex')  %or 'tex' but not 'latex'
figure(1)
t= [0:0.01:2*pi];
x = sin(t);
y = cos(t)
plot(t, x, t, y)
```

Output:

[image]

I tried the solution [here](https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/493071-how-to-put-en-dashes-instead-of-hyphens-for-a-negative-values-on-the-x-y-axis-and-colorbar-numbers), but the hyphens still remain there. I want the en-dash to appear because it's the standard sign for the negative sign. What is the correct way of getting an en-dash to appear instead of the hyphen?

Comment: The en-dash is not a minus sign. https://jakubmarian.com/hyphen-minus-en-dash-and-em-dash-difference-and-usage-in-english/

Comment: Oh, I was trying to see if I can get the minus signs in the matlab plot tick marks to be the same as that of latex.

Comment: Use `$-$` in LaTeX to get an actual minus sign.

Comment: I tried `yticklabels(ax, strrep(yticklabels(ax),'$-$','-'));`, but it didn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This post](https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/346436-how-to-use-latex-interpreter-for-xticklabels) at MATLAB Answers explains how to set the (default) interpreter for the axes' labels.

```
set(groot,'defaultAxesTickLabelInterpreter','latex');
```

You need to call this before plotting.

Having this set, the tick-labels will be interpreted as LaTeX code. Here is a comparison. The last two examples includes @XiangruiLi's answer (the next code snippets must be called after the plot was created):

```
yticklabels(gca, strrep(yticklabels(gca),'-','--'));
yticklabels(gca, strrep(yticklabels(gca),'-','$-$'));
```

- *none*: [image: none-ticks (original)]
- *latex*: [image: latex-ticks]
- *latex* + `strrep(...,'-','--'))`: [image: latex+strrep(--)]
- *latex* + `strrep(...,'-','$-$'))`: [image: latex+strrep($-$)]

While the last is probably what you wanted, note that this is certainly not the representation MATLAB intended. It is therefore the question if you really need/want to go through this fuzz.

Comment: Never mind, I had to put the `yticklabels` function after plotting the curves. I get the desired result. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

It seems to me you mis-used `strrep`. This worked for me:

```
yticklabels(ax, strrep(yticklabels(ax),'-','--'));
```

Answer (score 0):

Using the actual Unicode minus character should also work (also in Octave):

```
yticklabels(gca, strrep(yticklabels(gca),'-','−'));
```

In this case, there is no need to set the interpreter to LaTeX.